# Best practice to get pre-signed Amazon S3 download URL

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have the following code as part of a backend sample for generating download links which are valid for 15 minutes.

```
$url = "{$bucket}/{$key}";
$request = $this->s3Client->get($url);
return $this->s3Client->createPresignedUrl($request, '+15 minutes');
```

From what I understand, this makes a web request to Amazon, and I need to generate about 20-30 download links per pageload.

So how would I go about not abusing the Amazon API, while still allowing clients to download files? The 2 options I could think of are:

1. Generate the links client-side (either on click or on page load) and store them inside cookies, so that upon refresh, no extra API calls are made.
2. Generate the links server-side and store them either in cookies or in the session.

What I'm interested in is:

1. What's the best practice to generate the links (client- vs. server-side)?
2. How should I cache the links (ie. where)?

Comment: The best solution I can think of is to generate the links client-side, intercepting "onclick" events. In fact, you can't know how much time will pass from a customer GETting a page from your server, and a customer clicking on a link on your page, and this solution avoids the situation where  a customer clicks on a link which is expired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-issue, because creating a pre-signed URL with the AWS SDK for PHP does **not** make a request to AWS. You may also find that the [`S3Client::getObjectUrl()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObjectUrl) method is easier to use, since it is an abstraction of what you are doing now.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I didn't think to actually test this before asking, I just assumed it did a request, based off the `$request` variable and documentation. Tested now and it works, so... awesome! Thanks.

Comment: It builds a request object so it can create the signature for it, but then just returns the URL instead of performing the HTTP request to it. Glad it works out for you, :-)